# is google maps api V3 requires key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I developed one website in **google maps api V2**, now management is saying V2 is deprecated and convert in to V3. While googling the V3 i didn't see any api key? then how it works?

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

```
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAZIdFD1WVdDZkZtynpOarChQNeNa5CKtG0-vmTH0qjucdvCYnQxSdAQEaIYCVLr1JYZPtbiF0LjTojQ"
```

and how to convert from V2 to V3? should i develop it from scratch onwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps api v3 doesn't need a key like v2.  You are encouraged to use v3 because of the support for devices like iphone and android.

Googe maps api v3 has been implemented using [modified MVC framework.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) .

> Any state changes of an MVC object (such as a map) for example, are
>   handled through setters and getters of a particular format. As well,
>   all state of the MVC objects are stored as properties of that object,
>   and all observation of state changes through event handlers is of a
>   particular format as well.

[Learn More](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)

Answer (score 3):

Google Maps API v3 can be used both with and without a key.
You can [read this post](http://markus.tao.at/geo/google-maps-api-v3-is-in-town/) for clues how to migrate your application. Basically

> The second step in the migration process consists in renaming api
> calls and objects. The renaming follows the following pattern:
>
> GMarker -> google.maps.Marker
>
> GOverlay ->google.maps.Overlay
>
> GEvent -> google.maps.Event …