# Google Map Api Status Inactive

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am relatively new to working with the Google Map Api. Just recently I have been trying to upgrade from version 2 to version 3. The problem I'm having is that one day after signing up with Google to get a key, under the 'api access' tab on the google page, it says "status: Inactive". I was under the impression that the api was a free service that did not expire after one day. My question is, why am I getting this message and is there anyway to make the key active so that it works for more than one day? Any input you can give me would be helpful.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

When an API key is regenerated using the 'Generate new key...' link the old key is set to the 'Obsolete key' which remains active for around a day to allow you time to update any references to the old key.

Once the 'Active until' date has passed the 'Status' will show as 'inactive'. It is a little confusing and the 'Status' label should really say 'Obsolete key status'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow, but it sounds like you may have not enabled the V3 API on your project.

Where do you see that "inactive" status? I only found the word status in the Overview and Services tabs, not in the API Access tab. How does the V3 API show up for your project in the Overview and Services tabs?

Comment: This is what I see on the api access page                                                             Key for browser apps (with referers)
API key:  
**********(my key)
Referers:  Any referer allowed
Activated on:  Jan 26, 2012 12:52 PM
Activated by:  (myemailaddress)
Obsolete key:  ****(my old key)
Status:  Inactive                                                             In the overview and services tabs it says 'no known issues', the api v3 *is* activated.

Comment: google maps api version 3 dont requires key you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624656/is-google-maps-api-v3-requires-key

Answer (score 0):

V3 does not *require* keys, but it sounds like you are trying to use the correct kind of key, the new (Browser) ones you create in the API console at code.google.com/apis/console

I don't see any kind of status in my keys, have you tried creating a new key?

If that still doesn't help, would you paste the full URL you're using to load the API?
(feel free to omit a few characters in your key)

Answer (score 0):

Goto to [Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). There you activate `v3 API`. Then regenerate the key and use it.

Also [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) is tutorial how to use `v3 key`.